# Erro ao executar a linha StartActivityForResult()

Tags: android

Alguém conseguiria interpretar o porquê desse erro? A ideia é que todo algoritmo do Bluetooth esteja em uma classe separada, e com a principal só chamo os métodos. Segue o erro e o código.

```
package com.example.audio_auto;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AudioActivity extends Activity{

    private final static int VOICE_RESULT = 1;
    private ImageButton btnSpeack;
    private Button btSair, connect, enviar;
    private TextView txtText, txt;
    volatile boolean stopWorker;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    int counter;
    Blue BluClass = new Blue(); 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

        enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btSair = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btnSpeack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        btnSpeack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                        "Favor fala no microfone");

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RESULT);
                    txtText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    txtText.setText("");
                    // verifica();

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "nao suporta seu dispositivo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t.show();
                }
            }
        });

        btSair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BluClass.conect();
            }
        });

        enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == VOICE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtText.setText(matches.get(0).toString());
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String[] confirmar = { "bola", "dado" };

        for (int i = 0; i < confirmar.length; i++) {

            if (txtText.getText().toString().contains(confirmar[i])) {

                txt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                txt.setText("Otimo");
                break;
            } else {
                txt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                txt.setText("Comando Desconhecido !");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Classe onde irei colocar todo o algoritmo Bluetooth

```
package com.example.audio_auto;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Blue extends Activity{
    BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    public  void conect(){
        BluetoothAdapter BT = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter ();
        if (!BT.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.audio_auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.audio_auto.AudioActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Log:**

```
11-12 23:07:35.393: E/MtpService(29595): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
11-12 23:07:35.393: E/MtpService(29595): battPlugged Type : 2
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at com.example.audio_auto.Blue.conect(Blue.java:18)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at com.example.audio_auto.AudioActivity$3.onClick(AudioActivity.java:82)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
11-12 23:07:36.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30316):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 23:07:36.184: E/android.os.Debug(2027): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode herdar de `Activity` apenas para usar o método `startActivity` e correlatos.

Você só pode herdar de `Activity` unica e exclusivamente para criar `Activity's`, porque grande parte dos métodos dessa classe são dependentes de mudança de estados causada pelo ciclo de vida e gerariam erro por causa da ausência de estado, que foi seu caso.

Ao invés de herdar, basta exigir a presença de um `Context` como parâmetro. Ai basta usar esse `Context` para as chamadas que faria com a `Activity`. Se necessário poderá trocar a classe do parâmetro por `Activity`, mas acredito que o o `Context` já basta. Esse padrão é muito comum, poderá ver em outros projetos, não é nenhum problema.

Troque sua classe `Blue` para:

```
public class Blue extends Activity{
    BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    public  void conect(Context context){
        BluetoothAdapter BT = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (! BT.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
            context.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
}
```

E troque a chamada do método `connect` por `BluClass.conect(AudioActivity.this)`

Comment: Cara obrigado , não teste ainda pois estou no trampo mas valeu e quem arrumou a classe blue no site valeu tmbém pois não estava conseguindo formatar aqui no site direito (ficou todo embolado...)Obrigado wakim vou pesquisar mais sobre isso